# How to use Annotations in a Spring Boot Library (without Main Class)?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am new to spring boot and trying to figure out some of its working. Here I am getting Null Pointer Exception for the below implementation. I am not sure can we use @Autowire annotation for a Library project without a Main class. Maybe this sounds stupid,I believe we can do a @ComponentScan for the Library Project from a Service project that's created.My Question is looking at the below implementation is there any possibility to use annotation in the below library project, because Annotations are throwing NullPointerException for the below code?

**Library**

The below code is a library and it **Doesn't have a Main Class**

```
@Service
class Data {

   public String getData(){
      return "DATA";
   }
} 

class Access{

   @Autowired
   private Data data;

   public String myData(){
  
      return data.getData();   // Null pointer exception
   }
}
```

*pom.xml*

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

**Service**

The below code is of a **Service** which is accessing the above library

*Controller*

```
@GetMapping("/") 
String print(){

   // Accesses the Library
   Access access=new Access();
   return access.myData();

}

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.service", "com.library" }) // Hopes this Scans the library package
public class UserApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(UserApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

*pom.xml*

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.library</groupId>
    <artifactId>library</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

If I remove the **Autowired** from the library code, and create the object normally (using new keyword), everything works fine. So my question is, Main class with @SpringBootApplication is required inorder to use annotations, without a Main class can't we run it?

Comment: You can only use `@Autowired` in `@Component`s. `@Service` is itself annotated with `@Component` so services are components, too.

Comment: Do you have a bean of type `Access`. I don't see any annotation over `Access` class. Isn't NPE coming from the `access` variable in controller?

Comment: I and creating Access object like this , Access access=new Access(); The code works fine, if I am not using Autowire over the field "Data" inside the class Access and instead use Data obj =new data();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is annotate your library Access class with @Service Or @Component
And in your Controller class  create a field for Access class and autowire it.
Then use it inside your method

```
@Service
class Access{

@Autowired
private Data data;

public String myData(){

   return data.getData();
}
}

@RestController
class YourController {
@Autowired
Access access

@GetMapping("/") 
String print(){
return access.myData();

}
```

Answer (score 3):

The best practice if you're not relying on any Spring AOP features (such as `@Transactional`) is *don't do it at all*. `@Autowired` on fields is fragile; instead, use a normal constructor. Spring needs no annotations to instantiate a bean if you have only a single constructor, and this makes your class usable in a different DI environment or in plain Java (such as for testing).

Similarly, don't put `@Service` on a class in a library; clients who want it can simply use `@Import` to pull it in.

The one exception to this is that if you are providing [a Boot auto-configuration setup](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.developing-auto-configuration), that module will need to depend on `spring-boot-autoconfigure` to access the annotations. Note that it is customary to put your starter in a separate dependency that contains only the Boot classes and metafiles.

Answer (score 0):

With SpringBootApplication annotation, It will create application context with all required beans when starting the application. The object will be injected whenever it needed.

But in the Normal java application, the Object will be created while calling the new keyword.

@SpringBootApplication it required when you have @Autowired annotation otherwise you will get error.

Comment: The Service Project accessing the library project is having SpringBootApplication and in ComponentScan, I am specifying the Package name of the Library Project that's created. Isn't that enough?

Comment: You should have one main package and some other sub packages then all components will  be scan. Add Component annotations on Access and data class. Then Autowire the Access class to controller.